# If variable = new Model. Is new called every time you call the variable?

Tags: javascript

If `variable = new Model`

Is new called every time you call the variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. `variable` becomes a reference to `new Model`

Comment: So, I don't know any difference here? Can you tell me one?